# What is the best way to update an entity on LUIS from a SQL database

Tags: sql, botframework, azure-language-understanding, cortana

Currently I am using the Microsoft bot framework to create a cortana skill. With this bot I am using the luis framework as well as a sql database. My sql database is made through the Microsoft bot framework as well. The question I had is that I want to be able to update my luis entities so that when certain fields in my sql database are updated the corresponding entities will update as well. For example, I have a field of cities in my sql database and in my luis app I have a list entity contain all those cities that were in my sql database. Now when I update the sql database by adding another city into the field the luis app will automatically update itself such that the city entity list will update itself to contain that city.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [LUIS Programmatic SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/psSdkJson6/src/SDKs/CognitiveServices/dataPlane/Language/LUIS) to interact with your LUIS APP.

[Here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Services-LUIS-Programmatic-Console) is a good sample that shows how to use it.